# How do I load content in specific DIV after the page loads?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am wondering how I would load another PHP page into a DIV container after the parent page has loaded.  I need to design facebook/twitter share links that will show people my page with certain content loaded into a DIV.

I have a function working for clicking links, but I need it to work on page load rather than click (#results is the ID of the DIV I need content loaded into):

```
$(".Display a").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: $(this).attr("href"),
   success: function(msg){
     $("#results").html(msg);
   }
 });
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's .ready() event on the document:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Whatever you want to run
});
```

This will run as soon as the DOM is ready.

If you need your javascript to run after *everything* is loaded (including images) than use the .load() event instead:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // Whatever you want to run
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping your original click-handler, and triggering it with:

```
$(".Display a").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: $(this).attr("href"),
   success: function(msg){
     $("#results").html(msg);
   }
 });
 return false;
});

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.Display a').trigger('click');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the $.ajax() outside of the click event?

Instead of --

```
$(".Display a").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      success: function(msg){
        $("#results").html(msg);
      }
    });
  return false;
});
```

Try this --

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        success: function(msg){
                 $("#results").html(msg);
        }
       }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ //jQuery dom ready event

    $(".Display a").click(function() {
        ///you code
    }).click(); //trigger it at the page load

});
```